# How to use Protractor to test whether the correct image has loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jasmine, protractor

I am testing a website that can redirect in multiple ways, one of them is incorrect in all cases (and one is correct depending on context).

The most straight forward way in which I can identify the difference is to scrutinize the image which is loaded in a specific area.

I also notice that the paths of the CSS files (as well as image files) are different depending on the scenario, so it may be easier to test the paths instead of the image themselves (which are all named the same).

Unfortunately I can not share the code but in general terms, how could you use protractor to collect the full path data of a specific page's css (or image) file and compare that to what is expected?

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
mypic = element(by.css("img[src*='mypic.png']"));
expect(mypic.isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

Also maybe you want to do something specific if that image is found you do like below

```
mypic = element(by.css("img[src*='mypic.png']"));
browser.isElementPresent(mypic).then(function (result) {
    if(result){
        //  DO STUFF

    }
});
```

Comment: For me this test succeeds even if the image fails to load (because of a wrong img src url).

Comment: Agreed.  This won't work for broken image links as the <img> tag is still present in the DOM

Answer (score 1):

Without what you are attempting or your code it is difficult to tell but there should be two ways to do it-
1. The image name can be verified from the css. But in your case, the image names are same. So this won't work.
2. Check for the attributes of the image element. Height, width etc. and compare with the expected attributes. You can use `element.getAttribute("attribute")` to get particular values.